# Does Spring inject the same instance of a service into multiple components that use it?

Tags: java, spring, singleton

I have a little confusion or doubt, for example if I have the service:

```
@Service
public class SomeService() {
}
```

And then I have a controller like so:

```
    @RestController
    public class SomeController {
      private final SomeService someService;
      public SomeController(SomeService someService){
      this.someService = someService;
      }
    }
```

And then I have another controller like:

```
    @RestController
    public class AnotherController {
      private final SomeService someService;
      public AnotherController(SomeService someService){
      this.someService = someService;
      }
    }
```

Since Spring works with Singleton then I assume that the instance of someService that is at SomeController is the same that is at AnotherController right?

Comment: yes by default！

Comment: Here's a good overview of the different bean scopes (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes).  You'll notice that `Singleton` is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! by default,

Try this code:

the service:

```
@Service
public class SomeService() {
    public int num;
}
```

the controller1:

```
@RestController
public class SomeController {
    private final SomeService someService;
    public SomeController(SomeService someService){
        this.someService = someService;
        someService.num++;
        System.out.println(someService.num);
    }
}
```

the controller2:

```
@RestController
public class AnotherController {
    private final SomeService someService;
    public SomeController(SomeService someService){
        this.someService = someService;
        someService.num++;
        System.out.println(someService.num);
    }
}
```

put `@Scope("prototype")` on service can make service not be  Singleton

Answer (score 3):

yes,the default bean scope is Singleton in Spring,and Singleton means the two [someService] is the same ,you can print their hashCode and check.and may be you need this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes